# I want to get Lastest Record From current month

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table which keeps budget assigned for stores.

[image]

I want to get the record for all stores from current month for that i have written the query is:

```
SELECT * FROM table_budget WHERE store IN ([$STORE$]) AND MONTH(Date) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE())
            AND YEAR(Date) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE());
```

But i want to get the latest record if the store have two or more budgets for current month.

Comment: `order by date desc limit 1`, also this was asked a million times before. Please use the search function next time.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the end of your query:

```
AND NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT * FROM table_budget t2 
    WHERE t2.Store=table_budget.Store and t2.Date>table_budget.Date
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do a self join get latest record for each store

```
SELECT 
  a.* 
FROM
  table_budget a 
  LEFT JOIN table_budget b 
    ON a.store = b.store 
    AND a.Date < b.Date 
WHERE a.store IN ([ $STORE$ ]) 
  AND MONTH(a.Date) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE()) 
  AND YEAR(a.Date) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()) 
  AND b.store IS NULL ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try also the **LAST** function but not all application support it

So the workaround solution, as early stated, is to use the **ORDER BY** and then use **DESC** .
If you want just the last record add the **LIMIT**

e.g.
SELECT *column_name* FROM *table_name*
ORDER BY *column_name* DESC
LIMIT 1;

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM table_budget WHERE store IN ([$STORE$]) AND MONTH(Date) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE())
AND YEAR(Date) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()) ORDER BY Date DESC
LIMIT 1;
```